# What is the male counterpart of nubile?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there an accepted word that means a man (boy) ready for marriage?

I only found sites having nubile males or faunlets as near alternatives.

Comment: stripling - a juvenile between the onset of puberty and maturity

Comment: Of course, the age at which many males of our species *do* marry, and the age at which they are emotionally and morally *ready* for marriage, tend to diverge wildly.

Comment: 'Strapping'? @Kris 'stripling' sounds more negative, 'a mere stripling'.

Comment: @BrianDonovan as does the age at which they _can_ be ready - we often presume this sort of maturity comes from biology, but at least in modern culture it is dominated by cultural factors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stripling. OED:

> A youth, one just passing from boyhood to manhood.

Since *nubile* is so often used salaciously, this is a particularly zesty male equivalent.

If you want to go classical, try *ephebe* or *ephebus.*

Comment: There's nothing much zesty about 'stripling' as 'nubile' is today. See usage examples.

Answer (score 3):

There is not an exact male equivalent of *nubile* for the sense of being ready for marriage.

You can use ***marriageable*** as a gender neutral word. Nubile comes from Latin *nubilis* which means marriageable.

Today, nubile is used for "young and sexually attractive" woman. In the past, it had been used in the same meaning as in Latin, but now this use is only found in technical contexts.